# nested @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotations ignored where nested objects are generic when using eclispelink

Tags: generics, annotations, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

When marshaling an object tree I am making use of the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. Some adapters return objects of classes which themselves have the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation. This worked fine when I used the JAXB implementation packaged with websphere 7, but when I use `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory` the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotations on the objects returned by the first adapter are ignored. Is this a known issue, or am I doing something wrong?

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class,C.class);

        System.out.println(jc.getClass());

        Root root = new Root();
        A a = new A();
        root.a = a;

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

#### Root

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AAdapter.class)
   public A a;

}
```

#### A

```
public class A {

   public B b = new B();

}
```

#### B

```
public class B {

  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(GAdapter.class)
  @XmlElement(name="b")
  public G<C> gc = new G<C>();

  public B(){
    gc.t = new C();
  }
}
```

#### C

```
public class C {

    public String c = "Foo";

}
```

#### G

```
public class G<T> {

  T t;

}
```

Then the adapter for `A`...

```
public class AAdapter extends XmlAdapter<B, A> {

    @Override
    public A unmarshal(B b) throws Exception {

        A a = new A();
        a.b = b;

        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public B marshal(A a) throws Exception {

        return a.b;
    }

}
```

And the adapter for the generic type

```
public class GAdapter<T> extends XmlAdapter<T, G<T>> {

  @Override
  public G<T> unmarshal(T c) throws Exception {

    return new G<T>();
  }

  @Override
  public T marshal(G<T> g) throws Exception {

    return g.t;
  }

}
```

when marshaled with class `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<root>

    <a>

    <b xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="c">

        <c>Foo</c>

    </b>

    </a>

</root>
```

when marshaled with `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>

   <a>

      <b>forum237.C@23752375</b>

   </a>

</root>
```

I think the issue is with generic types. The goal is to skip the generic type from being marshaled, and only marshal `T`, as well as process `T`’s annotations, if any.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead.

I have been able to recreate this issue and confirm that is a bug (https://bugs.eclipse.org/350626).

**Root**

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AAdapter.class)
    public A<B> a;

}
```

**A**

```
package example;

public class A<T> {

    public T t;

}
```

**AAdapter**

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class AAdapter<T> extends XmlAdapter<T, A<T>> {

    @Override
    public A<T> unmarshal(T v) throws Exception {
        return new A<T>();
    }

    @Override
    public T marshal(A<T> v) throws Exception {
        return v.t;
    }

}
```

**B**

```
package example;

public class B {

}
```

**Demo**

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, B.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        A<B> a = new A<B>();
        a.t = new B();
        root.a = a;

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <a>example.B@3ecfff</a>
</root>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b"/>
</root>
```